# After bouncing of table to top App get crash

Tags: objective-c, uitableview, uiscrollview

I have implemented `UIScrollView` horizontally and put `UITableView` on that. And write the code for right and left direction on it.
Code is here:

```
CGFloat lastOffset_x = 0;
- (void)scrollViewDidScroll:(UIScrollView *)scrollView{
     CGFloat currentOffSet_x = scrollView.contentOffSet.x;
     if(lastOffset_x > currentOffSet_x){
         //direction left
     }else{
         //direction right
     }
     lastOffset_x = scrollView.contentOffSet.x;
}
```

After bouncing of table on top app goes in left direction and reload table with wrong values and crashes.
Please help me. I worked on it 3 days but didn't find the solution.

Comment: can You explain what else you added on scrollview except tableview and how much width of =content size of scrollview are having?

Comment: I added one UILabel and UITableView. content size of scrollview is dynamic.    self.feedsScrollView.contentSize = CGSizeMake(categoryary.count * self.feedsScrollView.frame.size.width, self.feedsScrollView.frame.size.height);

Comment: add your crash log report.